# PUB/SUB Message Queue with server side filtering?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, kafka, activemq, messaging

I am looking for a message queue to realize a chat application.

The most important requirement is: when a subscriber specifies a filter criteria, all the messages need to be filtered **on the server side**.

Unfortunately I don't find definite answers to the question if all those MQs around are filtering on the client side or on the server side.

It seems to me that most of the MQs are either not supporting filter criteria at all, or they are filtering on the client side (Kafka, ZeroMQ).

Maybe you guys can lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a JMS topic subscription with a "selector" (what JMS calls a "filter") on [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) then the filtering is done on the server side.

Comment: I will have a look at that. Thank you very much!